# Is "Greek School" really a thing as portrayed in "My Big Fat Greek Wedding"

Tags: realism, my-big-fat-greek-wedding

At the end of the movie ["My Big Fat Greek Wedding"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/My_Big_Fat_Greek_Wedding) it shows the protagonist sending her first child to Greek School to learn the language

Is this actually common in the Greco-American community? While I know of Jews sending their kids to Hebrew school,  I have never heard of Italian-Americans sending their kids to Italian school, or Polish-Americans to Polish school. Is this unique to the Greek ethnic group, occur in more ethnic groups than I realize, or "not really a thing"?  I realize that the author of the story, [Nia Vardalos](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nia_Vardalos) is of that culture and would presumably know what is authentic...

Comment: A quick google search for "Greek school Chicago" gives a bunch of results, so yes, this is clearly a thing. Opa!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely, most cultural specific churches (Greek Orthodox, Armenian, etc)  also have "schools"  for teaching Language and traditions to 2nd generation children to assure they continue to be recognized and celebrated.